# Wronskian has constant sign

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I don't follow the part in green. Surely if $W(x)$ is zero at some point at say some $c \in (a,b)$ this just implies that $W'(c)=0$ as $p>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rearrange the last displayed equation to
$$ (pW)'=0, $$
which integrates to
$$ W(x) = \frac{A}{p(x)}. $$
Since $p>0$, the only way for this to be zero at one point is for $A$ to be zero. But then $W=0$ for all $x$.